# How do I calculate the stress distribution (von Mises stress) on the top cap of a vacuum vessel cylinder subjected to 77 kPa, h=600 mm and dia=200mm

Tags: stresses, pressure-vessel

I have designed a vacuum vessel 600 mm deep and 200 mm in diameter with a thickness of 2mm from SS 316 and simulated pressure distribution using FEA. I want to theoretically validate the findings and calculate the stress distribution as a result of the 77 kPa vacuum specifically on the top cap. I have tried using the hoop stress and axial stress formulae, and resultant von Mises stress which give values much smaller than the calculated values. Am I missing out on something? Please help.